# Discrete structures Logic exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I  am a beginner please help solve this

What is the contrapositive of the statement: "If you understand the material, you will pass this test."

Comment: Do you know what the word "contrapositive" means? Is there somewhere you could look it up?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ denote: "You understand the material."

Let $Q$ denote: "You will pass the test."

Then the statement you are starting with is the *implication*$\;\;$

"If (you understand the material), then (you will pass the test)": $$P \rightarrow Q: \;\text{If $P$, then $Q$.}\tag{(1) implication}$$

The *contrapositive* of the implication $P\rightarrow Q$ is given by $$\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P: \;\text{If not $Q$, then not $P$.}\tag{contrapositive of (1)}$$

Here, the contrapositive of your statement "translates" to the following:

$$\text{"If you do not pass the test, then you do not understand the material."}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ and $Q$ denote statements such that $P \implies Q$, then the contrapositive of this is just $$ Not \; Q \implies Not \; P $$

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive would be:

If you will not pass this test, you do not understand the material.

This is because the contrapositive of **P --> Q** is **not Q --> not P**, where P and Q denote statements.